# Input.GetKeyDown need to press button more than once to work

Tags: unity, c#, input, scripting, keyboard

So in Unity3D I'm checking for `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)` for stuff like pickups and opening doors. Sometimes it doesn't work the first time I press it and I must press the key `E` like 2-4 times, and then it works. What could be the possible reason for this to occur?

As a further note, `Input.GetKeyDown()` is being called from `OnTriggerStay()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity chose to reset the flag that services `Input.GetKeyDown` every frame as [is noted in their docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html).

> You need to call this function from the Update function, since the state gets reset each frame. It will not return true until the user has released the key and pressed it again.

So trying to use it from `OnTriggerStay()` will most likely not work as there's a good chance that `Update()` will occur before `OnTriggerStay()` is called and reset the keys state (it also depends on when and how they handle user input from how the operating system reports it). There's even more complexity (physics timesteps are different from `Update()` timesteps, and [`OnTriggerStay()` isn't called every frame](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html)) so you're basically relying on a race condition to check `E` which is not reliable.

Fixing this isn't so easy as mentioned by @Gnemlock (originally I had a simple flag set using `GetKeyDown`).

There are a couple ways to fix this though. @Gnemlock mentions `Input.GetKey` which returns true as long as you're holding the key down.

```
private bool isEPressed = false;

void Update()
{
    isEPressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E);
}
```

You can also just use an OR expression which you need to clear yourself later

```
private bool isEPressed = false;

void Update()
{
    isEPressed = isEPressed || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E);
}
void WasEPressed()
{
    //You might want to do a timestamp check here too
    //for like 250ms or something small so that it
    //doesn't stay active forever
    bool ret = isEPressed;
    isEPressed = false;
    return ret;
}
```

If you want to go really modular, you might use a C# event that the trigger subscribes to in `OnTriggerEnter()` (and unsubscribes to when leaves) but that might be too complex for your needs.

Comment: What do you mean in the last paragraph by flag?

Comment: Updated answer, just a simple boolean flag that when it's true, you're player is pressing E. Then in your OnTriggerStay(), you'd do like `collider.getComponent<Player>().isEPressed` (of course you'd have to check to make sure it's a player too).

Comment: GetKeyDown specifically finds out if they key *has just been pressed*. This doesn't always work in non Update methods, because Update may have run more than once since they key press and eventual check. That appears to be the problem asker is having, and this does not fix it. This solution simply caches the value locally, but under the same conditions, the value still returns to false early.

Comment: @Gnemlock Ah, shit, I get `GetKey` and `GetKeyDown` mixed up all the time in my head. I'll update my answer

Comment: I think you still have logic errors.. Your setting `isEPressed` to `false` just before returning it, effectively making the whole function redundant.

Comment: @Gnemlock Fixed, meant that to be `ret`, not `isEPressed`

Comment: This still has logic errors.. Your saying `isDown = GetKeyDown() || isDown`, so initially, once `isDown = true`, it will *stay* `true`. You only reset it when you actually *check* it, which would only happen when you *need* to check it. So ultimately, your not finding out it a key was just pressed; your finding out if they key *was* pressed since the last check. I guess this works if were always checking for the key, but in the given scenario, this is clearly not the case.

Comment: Might I recommend creating a test project in Unity, and testing your solution prior to edit/post?

Comment: @Gnemlock That's actually the point, I put a comment suggesting that a timeout could be added to the checking function for the last E keypress which would limit the length of time the key press actually _does_ something. The concept is there, I just felt it becomes a design decision to implement those extra things like that so if the user wants to, they can do it. Also creating a test project is  probably not a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

`GetKeyDown()` tells us if the user pressed the key down during the *last* `Update()` function. This allows us to react during the frame where the button has been pressed, without reacting in the same way for each consecutive frame where the key *is still being* pressed.

This makes things a bit more tricky, trying to perform the same check in an `OnTriggerStay()` method. `Update()` runs as many times as your hardware can handle, per second. It is entirely possible for *two or more* `Update()` cycles to run in between pressing the button, and triggering `OnTriggerStay()`. Remember, collision is physics based, and only checks with `FixedUpdate()`, which typically runs far less infrequently than `Update()`.

In the end, we could and up with an `OnKeyDown()` that *initially* flips to `true`, but flips back to `false` before we actually get to check it. For this reason, *caching* this value (as suggested in an alternate answer) runs into this same problem.

Having experienced this, before, your best bet is to use `OnKey()`. `OnKey()` checks if the key is down, regardless. If the key is down, it will ***always*** return `true`. In situations where this would lead to issues resulting from always checking the key, you can then start to think about caching a local variable to keep record of whether they key *has just been pressed*, for the purposes of your `OnTriggerStay()` method, or if the key *is still being pressed* from a previous `OnTriggerStay()`.

Comment: I feel like this still has problems with it though? If you have a higher (longer) timestep and you press and release before it finishes, you can still miss it. More realistically, if the game has abnormally high latency it might miss it too.

Comment: @Coburn, if you cache your own version of `GetKeyDown()`, no you won't. You would accommodate for those problems when setting it up (FYI, read the question; the question is 'why does this happen', not 'so what do I do', so I'm not going into too much detail on a solution. There are various ways to do this, and it *is* pretty simple.)

Answer (score 0):

I went searching for exactly this, and with Coburns suggestion I made the following that will more accurately track when something changes to use for `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events.

It does need to be run at least once per frame to track accurately as is its only shortcoming as it uses `UnityEngine.Time.frameCount` as for its timekeeping.

````
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeObserver
{
    private int _lastStart = -2;
    private int _lastEnd = -1;

    private bool Last => _lastStart > _lastEnd;

    protected bool HasChange(bool current)
    {
        if(current == Last)
            return _lastStart == Time.frameCount
                || _lastEnd == Time.frameCount;

        if(current)
            _lastStart = Time.frameCount;
        else
            _lastEnd = Time.frameCount;

        return true;
    }
}

public class InputChangeObserver : ChangeObserver
{
    public KeyCode KeyCode { get; private set; }

    public bool KeyChange => HasChange(Input.GetKey(KeyCode));

    public bool Key => Input.GetKey(KeyCode);
    public bool KeyDown => KeyChange && Input.GetKey(KeyCode);
    public bool KeyUp => KeyChange && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode);

    public InputChangeObserver(KeyCode keyCode)
    {
        KeyCode = keyCode;
    }
}
```
````